# Escape curly braces in Windows Powershell and Gulp

Tags: javascript, powershell, visual-studio-code, gulp

I'm working on Windows in vscode terminal and I'm writing a task for Gulp that concats some .js scripts. I've added a header option on the command:

```
gulp myTask -t '(function(){'
```

The console throws this error `"{ not expected at this moment"`. How can I escape the curly brace in that context? 
I searched the internet but I could not find anything that works.

Comment: i've never seen that error message phrasing in powershell - are you SURE that error is form powershell?

Comment: The output is in spanish, thats why I think it comes from powershel, but now that you mention it, maybe it's an output coming from Gulp,

Comment: i would test that in a CMD shell to confirm the source. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

The escape character for powershell is a backtick(`).
This is jsut above the tab key before the num key 1.

Comment: did u try giving a space after parenthesis like - gulp myTask -t '(function() `{'

Comment: It worked, but the backtick was added to the script, so I tryed without the backtick an the space and it worked. Tnx